# How to check collection mongo db in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to check if that collection already exist or not. If exist, the collection will dropped and add the new data, if not exist the collection will be created:

Below my code :

```
 MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("coba");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MongoIterable <String> collection =  database.listCollectionNames();
    for(String s : collection) {
        if(s.equals("collectionName")) {
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details on how to access the database and context.